# NDEigenvalues complains not Hermitian with large dimension differential operator

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

The following snippet calculates eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a null operator (just as an example):

```
n = 10;
us = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["u", ToString[i]]][x, y], {i, n}];
NDEigenvalues[
 Join[
  Table[0.0, {i, n}],
  Table[DirichletCondition[us[[i]] == 0, True], {i, n}]
  ],
 us,
 {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-5.0, -5.0}, {5.0, 5.0}],
 6
 ]
```

With `n` less than 10, everything works perfectly. For `n>10`, `NDEigenvalues` complains `Eigensystem::herm: The matrix SparseArray[Automatic,<<3>>] is not Hermitian or real and symmetric.`

Is this a precision issue? How to avoid this?

**Edit**:
The official suggestion to avoid this problem is to set InterpolationOrder, as shown in the link posted by @user21.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can avoid that:

```
n = 10;
us = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["u",
    StringPadLeft[ToString[i], 2, "0"]]][t, x, y], {i, n}];
NDEigenvalues[
 Join[Table[0.0, {i, n}], 
  Table[DirichletCondition[us[[i]] == 0, True], {i, n}]], us, {x, 
   y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-5.0, -5.0}, {5.0, 5.0}], 6]
{1.5777218104420236`*^-29, 1.8932661725304283`*^-29, \
2.208810534618833`*^-29, 2.8398992587956425`*^-29, \
3.470987982972452`*^-29, 5.048709793414476`*^-29}
```

Note that I changed the way the dependent variables are generated to:

```
us = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["u",
StringPadLeft[ToString[i], 2, "0"]]][t, x, y], {i, n}]
{u01[x, y], u02[x, y], u03[x, y], u04[x, y], u05[x, y], u06[x, y], 
 u07[x, y], u08[x, y], u09[x, y], u10[x, y]}
```

This has the property that

```
Sort[us]==us
True
```

In essence what you are seeing is an issue discussed section [Ordering of Dependent Variable Names](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) in the documentation; though it might not be quite that obvious.

How did I arrive at this conclusion? One thing you can do is to follow [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437) to see what is happening inside. We start by making a coarser mesh and using `ProcessEquations` to generate the FEM data.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-5.0, -5.0}, {5.0, 5.0}], 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 20, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
n = 10;
us = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["u", ToString[i]]][t, x, y], {i, n}];
(*us = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["u",
    StringPadLeft[ToString[i], 2, "0"]]][t, x, y], {i, n}];*)
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   Join[Table[D[us[[i]], t] == 0, {i, n}], 
    Table[us[[i]] == 0 /. t -> 0, {i, n}]], 
   us, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] m, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
```

Next we extract the FEM data from the `NDSolve` state object.

```
femd = state["FiniteElementData"];
bcd = femd["BoundaryConditionData"];
md = femd["FEMMethodData"];
pdec = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
vd = state["VariableData"];
sd = state["SolutionData"][[1]];
```

And discretize the system:

```
{l, s, d, mm} = DiscretizePDE[pdec, md, sd]["SystemMatrices"];
```

Now, look at that:

```
MatrixPlot[d]
```

[image]

This does not look, right. It seems that the ordering of the variables is not correct. You can try with n=9 to see the difference. This gave me clue to look at the dependent variable ordering. And sure enough looking at

```
NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "DependentVariables"]
{u1, u10, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9}
```

revealed the culprit. And the fix is, as described above, to use a dependent variable ordering that does not suffer from an internal reordering. Surely this is very unfortunate behavior of the `NDSolve` function family in conjunction to the FEM. The fact that `NDSolve` did this reordering was done long before the FEM got implemented and it seems very hard to fix. Which is unfortunate. Sorry about that.